Thermal fuse replacement
My heater (pictured) has stopped working. The manual states that one of the features is a thermal fuse that would need to be replaced if blown. I'm wondering:

Which element is the thermal fuse? (Is it the one in the white oval?)
How do I tell if it's blown?




You should check the continuity between the connections of the part you have circled in white.
A thermal fuse is usually something like this 
This                                                                 is a thermostatic switch.

You need constant continuity across the thermal fuse, but the thermostat will open and close according to it prescribed parameters.  ( so not always showing continuity.)
Your wiring may be different than the diagram. However the components are still the components.  You need to get the unit powered to check the draw of the motor and fan and elements.  Then you can determine if there is a component producing too much resistance (Draw) and is the cause of the fuse blowing.

TY. Can you clarify one more time which one is the fuse: the U-shaped circled in white or the cylinder in your second picture? (I found that the U-shape element is called a fuse: https://carrollparts.com/marley/Y4520-2030-000/)

I fixed the pic positioning. what you circled in white is a fuse.

So SiHa got it wrong?

@Wynne, yes....

OK, I tested it and it's blown.  Before I buy the replacement, can I test whether it's the only culprit by connecting the two spade directly and seeing if the heater works?

@Wynne, that is a risk.  If there is a strong resistance damage could result to other components, possibly a fire could result.    I cannot suggest that you do that.  I would recommend buying 2 fuses.    If you feel the absolute need to try, maybe a quick touch to just see if the motor turns.  However you know the fuse is blown and need replaced.

@RMDman Fair enough - I've deleted my answer.
